# The spectacular unblur demo from 2011, what happened to the tool?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, blur, plugin

I am talking about this demo from 2011:

[image]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxjiQoTp864

The plugin they show seems to have mapped the motion of the camera.

But I have never seen such a tool in PS.

What happened to this feature?

Comment: It's in Photoshop, under *Filter > Sharpen > Shake reduction*.  [see an example](https://imgur.com/I6KMuGF)

Answer (score 0):

Its in Photoshop. Its called smart sharpen and shake reduction. (which are both essentially same tool with different kernel estimator)